# how to get modified date of the file in python

Tags: python, file, python-typing, temporary-files, last-modified

I have a file (it could be type of **typing.IO** or **tempfile.SpooledTemproraryFile**)

How I can get the date of the last modification, I don't know what is the path to the file, the only thing that I have is a file.

My code:

```py
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile
from typing import IO

def partition_csv( file: Union[IO, SpooledTemporaryFile] ):
#   read last modification time of file
```

Comment: How was the file created? And is there any hint where the file _might_ be located?

Comment: I have a function that gets the file as a parameter, so I do not have any other information related to how it was created, where it could be located, etc.

Comment: The file parameter is of what type? Please provide some code if possible too.

Comment: I have updated question with small example

Answer (score 0):

you can change `file_name` to the name of your file.

```
import os.path
import time

def get_modified_date(file_name):
    file_path=f"./{file_name}"
    # more info about os.path.getmtime function here: 
    # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime
    modified_time = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
    return time.ctime(modified_time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_name = "my_file.txt"
    modified_date = get_modified_date(file_name)
    print(modified_date)
```

Answer (score -1):

#### If file is of type `SpooledTemporaryFile`:

1. To get the directory where the temporary files in your system are stored, use `tempfile.gettempdir()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir.
2. To get the last modification time: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime.

```py
import os
import tempfile

def partition_csv( file: Union[IO, SpooledTemporaryFile]):
    os.path.getmtime(tempfile.gettempdir() + file)
```